# When using Application.OnKey, why does Ctrl+Shift+Letter work, but Ctrl+Alt+Letter does not work?

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to use Ctrl+Alt+Letter to run a macro. It does not appear that letter combinations will work with either Ctrl+Alt+Letter or Alt+Ctrl+Letter. Ctrl+Shift+Letter works. Is there a restriction that precludes using Ctrl and Alt with letters?

Answer (score 3):

The following <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>letter</kbd> combinations (not exhaustive at all!) work for me:

```
Sub Foo()
    MsgBox "Foo"
End Sub

Sub Bar()
    Application.OnKey "^%z", "Foo" ' Ctrl + Alt + z
    Application.OnKey "^%y", "Foo" ' Ctrl + Alt + y
    Application.OnKey "^%x", "Foo" ' Ctrl + Alt + x
    Application.OnKey "^%w", "Foo" ' Ctrl + Alt + w
    ' skip v, Ctrl + Alt + v is Paste Special
End Sub
```

My guess would be you specified upper-case letters, e.g. `Z`, `Y`, `X`, `W`, in `OnKey`. You need the lower-case versions, or to use <kbd>Shift</kbd> if an uppercase letter.